# efficient mirroring of values with .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two tables. I want to mirror the values from one table to another. The current implementation i have is this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">  
        $("#textfield1, #textfield2, #textfield3, #select1").on("keyup keypress blur click change", function(event){        
            $("input[type='text']#copytextfield1").val( $("[type='text']#textfield1").val() );
            $("input[type='text']#copytextfield2").val( $("[type='text']#textfield2").val() );
            $("input[type='text']#copytextfield3").val( $("[type='text']#textfield3").val() );
            $("input[type='text']#copytextfield4").val( $("select#select1").val() );        
        });         
    </script>
```

as you can see, the names are quite similar. the only difference is that the mirroring elements have 'copy'. can you suggest of ways to make this more efficient? maybe take advantage of the naming convetion?

Comment: `#copytextfield4` mapping to `#select1` makes it harder to refactor this into a loop. Are there other special cases? Also, you don't need `input[type='text']` or `select` before id selectors, it actually makes your code less readable *and* less efficient.

Comment: i only added input[type='text'] and select because i remember vaguely that adding them actually makes it more efficient. no im not really sure what i read. can you direct me to some references saying the opposite?

Comment: Sure, [documentation for id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), first paragraph in `Description` section. It's quite logical actually: `#foo` only has to match the `id`, `something#foo` also has to check the element against the `something` selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done like this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">  
        $("#textfield1, #textfield2, #textfield3, #select1").on("keyup keypress blur click change", function(event){
            for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
                $("#copytextfield" + i).val( $("#textfield" + i).val() );
            }
            $("input[type='text']#copytextfield4").val( $("select#select1").val() );        
        });         
    </script>
```

The ID of the select causes some trouble though, so if you change the id of all the fields to something like input1 - input4 instead, it could be refactored even more.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $("#input1, #input2, #input3, #input1").on("keyup keypress blur click change", function(event){
            for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
                $("#copytextfield" + i).val( $("#input" + i).val() );
            }       
        });         
    </script>
```

Comment: thanks. i never knew that javascript variables could be handled like this

Comment: @user571099 Happy it helped! The jQuery selector is a simple JavaScript string, so you can create it the way you want, and it will be concatenated before it is sent to the jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this: made a **demo for you as well:** http://jsfiddle.net/6hwLS/4/

idea is to take the numeric value out from the end and use them with `$(this)` object:

Also you don't need `input[type='text']` or `select` as `id` are unique and identify DOM elements uniquely.

Hope this helps, `:)`

**like this:**

```
$("#textfield1, #textfield2, #textfield3, #select1")
    .on("keyup keypress blur click change", function(event) {

        var theNum = parseInt($(this).attr("id").match(/\d+$/)); // will return last numeric value

         $("#copytextfield"+theNum).val($("#textfield"+theNum).val());      
         if( theNum === 4) {
            $("#copytextfield"+theNum).val($("#select1").val());
        }
}); ​
```